# R Shiny - Saving results of dynamically created modules

Tags: r, shiny, r6, shinymodules

I encountered the following problem that I have tried to summarize in this minimal reproducible example.

The app should be able to dynamically create modules and render the UI of the module - `obj_UI` in my example - in a tab of the tabsetpanel `objTP`. Each of this modules should render a `R6` object of type `objR6`. I would like to save the resulting `R6` objects into a `reactiveValues` variable called `objCollection` and display it in the `verbatimTextOutput` called `displayValues`.

When clicking on the `input$addObject` button, I get the error message `"Error in <-: cannot add bindings to a locked environment"`. I believe the problem lies in the `observeEvent` at the very end of the example, but cannot figure what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(R6)

# Simple R6 object
objR6 <- R6::R6Class(
  "objR6",
  public = list(
    identifier = NULL,
    selected_value = NULL,

    initialize = function(identifier) {
      self$identifier <- identifier
    }
  )
)

# Module Ui
obj_UI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectInput(NS(id, "value"), "Chose Value", letters)
  )
}

# Module Server
obj_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    obj <- reactiveVal(objR6$new(id))

    observeEvent(input$value, {
      newObj <- obj()$clone()
      newObj$selectec_value <- input$value
      obj(newObj)
    })


    return(reactive(obj()))

  })
}


# Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("objSelection", "Select Object",
                choices = "",
                selectize = FALSE,
                size = 10),
    actionButton("addObject", "Add Object"),
    actionButton("rmvObject", "Remove Object"),
    tabsetPanel(id = "objTP"),
    verbatimTextOutput("displayValues")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  objCount <- reactiveVal(0)
  objCollection <- reactiveValues(objects = list())

  # Reaction on action button "addObject"
  observeEvent(input$addObject, {

    # Add another item
    objCount(objCount() + 1)
    newObjName <- paste0("Object_", objCount())
    updateSelectInput(session, "objSelection", choices = c(paste0("Object_", 1:objCount())))

    # Append the object tabset panel
    appendTab("objTP", tabPanel(newObjName, obj_UI(newObjName)), select = TRUE)

  })

  # Reaction on action button "rmvObject"
  observeEvent(input$rmvObject, {
    delObjName <- paste0("Object_", objCount())
    objCount(objCount() - 1)
    updateSelectInput(session, "objSelection", choices = c(paste0("Object_", 1:objCount())))
    removeTab("objTP", target = delObjName)

  })

  # Implement the server side of module
  observeEvent(objCount(), {
    if (objCount() > 0) {

      for (i in 1:objCount()) {
        identifier <- paste0("Object_", i)
        observeEvent(obj_Server(identifier), {
          objCollection$objects[[identifier]] <- obj_Server(identifier)
        })
      }
    }

    # Ouput the selected values
    output$displayValues <- renderPrint({
      reactiveValuesToList(objCollection)
    })

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I get an error in moduleserver function (the app cannot find it). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Alessio do you have the latest `shiny`? it was introduced in 1.5.0

Comment: The problem is in this part: `newObj <- obj$clone()`. It has to be `newObj <- obj()$clone()`, however now I get the error message "Error in <-: cannot add bindings to a locked environment". I'm not well versed in R6, my guess is that something goes wrong with the environments/R6 objects `shiny` is built upon

Comment: Thanks @starja. I have edited the post correcting this but get the same error message as you do.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/r6-class-reactivevalues-property-and-instantiation/31025) helps? Otherwise it may be worth a shot to make an [issue]() and ask for the correct usage of R6 objects in reactives

Comment: @starja Thanks, the link is quite interesting. But in my app, I would not want reactives to be part of the R6 class as the class should also be working outside of the shiny-context. Meanwhile, I found a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following minimal reproducible example is an answer to the problem above. In comparison to the code above I corrected a typo in the server function of the module and also put the initialization of the server part in the `observeEvent` for the `input$addObject` and removed the `observeEvent` for `objCount()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(R6)

# Simple R6 object
objR6 <- R6::R6Class(
  "objR6",
  public = list(
    identifier = NULL,
    selected_value = NULL,

    initialize = function(identifier) {
      self$identifier <- identifier
    }
  )
)

# Module Ui
obj_UI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    selectInput(NS(id, "value"), "Chose Value", letters)
  )
}

# Module Server
obj_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {

    obj <- reactiveVal(objR6$new(id))

    observeEvent(input$value, {
      newObj <- obj()$clone()
      newObj$selected_value <- input$value
      obj(newObj)
    })


    return(reactive(obj()))

  })
}


# Shiny App
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidPage(
    selectInput("objSelection", "Select Object",
                choices = "",
                selectize = FALSE,
                size = 10),
    actionButton("addObject", "Add Object"),
    actionButton("rmvObject", "Remove Object"),
    tabsetPanel(id = "objTP"),
    verbatimTextOutput("displayValues")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  objCount <- reactiveVal(0)
  objCollection <- reactiveValues(objects = list())

  # Reaction on action button "addObject"
  observeEvent(input$addObject, {

    # Add another item
    objCount(objCount() + 1)
    newObjName <- paste0("Object_", objCount())
    updateSelectInput(session, "objSelection", choices = c(paste0("Object_", 1:objCount())))

    # Append the object tabset panel
    appendTab("objTP", tabPanel(newObjName, obj_UI(newObjName)), select = TRUE)

    # Add the server component of the module
    observeEvent(obj_Server(newObjName), {
      objCollection$objects[[newObjName]] <- obj_Server(newObjName)
    })


  })

  # Reaction on action button "rmvObject"
  observeEvent(input$rmvObject, {
    delObjName <- paste0("Object_", objCount())
    if (objCount() > 0) {
      objCount(objCount() - 1)
      removeTab("objTP", target = delObjName)
      objCollection$objects[[delObjName]] <- NULL
      if (objCount() > 0) {
        updateSelectInput(session, "objSelection", choices = c(paste0("Object_", 1:objCount())))
      } else {
        updateSelectInput(session, "objSelection", choices = "")
      }
    }
  })

  # Ouput the selected values
  output$displayValues <- renderPrint({
    lapply(reactiveValuesToList(objCollection)$objects, function(i) {i()})
  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```